# What does hinduism say about exorcism

Tags: vedas, sects

What are views of different sects of hinduism ( like Shaivism, Shaktism, etc) about exorcism and is there any vedic reference to it?

Comment: Atharva Veda has some mantras for exorcism, but one must be careful in the term exorcism as there is no 'devil' in Vedanta. Also, these mantras should be done only by a brahmin versed in the Atharva Veda as any mispronunciation can have the opposite effect.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Do you think that all Hindu exorcists today, have studied the Vedas?

Comment: No, most are charlatans that prey are weak minds.